# precompile header and STL library

Tags: templates, gcc, stl, precompiled-headers

I'm using precompiled header for C++ project (using gcc 5.3.1).

I've included lot of Standard Library headers within my precompiled header.

```
...
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
...
```

But since those are mainly templates, do I need to specify them for every type I'm using in the precompiled header ?

Eg:

```
void touchStdVectorFloat(const std::vector<float> & vec) {}
void touchStdVectorInt(const std::vector<int> & vec) {}
...
```

In this way the used template are known at precompiled header generation time

Is it usefull or useless ?

Comment: You may want to check a few words. The STL was used with C++ prior to 1998, but never with C. And it used `<vector.h>`; `<vector>` is from the C++ Standard Library (no T). `<string>` didn't even come from the STL.

Comment: ok thanks, I've edited my post

Answer (score 1):

A pre-compiled header is just a replacement for a regular header include.  It does not matter if it contains templates or no, and the compilation model does not change.  Any piece of code which instantiates a template still needs a definition of the template in scope.